# Verificar sintaxis js en Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

Me gustaria saber si Visual Studio 2017 tiene una herramienta para verificar la sintaxis de java script cuando se compila un proyecto.

Actualmente si tengo un error un archivo js, solo me doy cuenta cuanto lo ejectuto y el browser  reporta el error.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: También puedes utilizar [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

En visual studio 2017 esto ya viene incluido, si no está habilitado debes hacerlo en la siguiente opción:

Herramientas->Opciones->Editor de texto->JavaScript/TypeScript->"Habilitar el nuevo JavaScript Languaje Service"

con esto ya te debería estar verificando la sintaxis de javascript el problema es que javascript de por si es muy permisivo, te pongo como ejemplo el código siguiente:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  var a = i;
}
console.log(a);
```

el código de arriba te compilara y te ejecutara sin problemas y es que en javascript cuando declaras una variable te las manda todas hasta arriba de la sección de código donde se están ejecutando pero esto puede generar confusión a la hora de debuggear una código javascript por lo que te recomiendo utilizar el modo estricto de javascript, ejemplo:

```
"use strict";
for(i=0;i<10;i++){ // error
  var a = i;
}
console.log(a); // error
```

para este caso dara error en el uso de la variable `i` porque no está previamente definida y con el caso de `console.log` pasará algo parecido ya que la variable `a` esta definida en una sección de código a la que no tiene acceso, usando el modo estricto el validador de javascript te detecta estos problemas.

Ahora, javascript tiene otro tipo de problemas y es por su naturaleza, javascript es un lenguaje interpretado, no compilado o precompilado, ¿qué significa esto? Pues a modo de ejemplo pondremos el siguiente código:

```
var Persona = { nombre: "Juan"};
console.log(Persona.apellido);
```

El código de arriba no me detecta error y es porque no sabe que la variable apellido no existe hasta que la ejecuta y es por esto que la mayoría de los lenguajes son compilados o pre compilados para detectar este tipo de errores, con respecto a esto no tengo el conocimiento si existe o no una herramienta para detectar estos errores. Espero esta información te sirva, Saludos.